Python Jwt Error "Algorithm not found" and another error "do you Cryptography component is installed"
I am using python jwt to get a jwt token using algorithm RS512, but I keep getting error that algorithm is not found.
Also, I get an error that no cryptography component is found. I have installed pycryptodome though.
Can anyone help on resolving above issues? Below is my code:
def generate_jwt_token(self):
    privateKeyPath = './config/privateKey.pem'
    payload = {'name': 'abc'}
    with open(privateKeyPath ,'rb') as f:
        privateKey = f.read()
    jwtToken = jwt.encode(payload, key=privateKey, algorithm='RS512')
    print(jwtToken)


error "do you Cryptography component is installed" - I doubt that this is the error message that you got. Please edit your question to add the precise error message.

Got the answer for algorithm not found :-
Instead of installing pycrypto or pycryptodome, install the crypto component along with jwt.
pip install pyjwt[crypto]
